# Need a fast updating group calendar for a support-desk

Tags: calendar

We were asked to implement a fast updating group calendar for a support-desk which has to allocate transportation for customers. We run several Windows XP workstations and a few notebooks in a domain based network (Linux Samba fileserver and domain controller).

We did some experiments with Google Calendar which does meet our requirements, but the fact that it updates too slowly. This may lead to clashing dates if two helpdesk-persons allocate the same timeslot for a customer without knowing about the other. As commonly the next available time-slot is taken if requested this will even occur quite frequently.

Can someone recommend a group calendar suitable for this situation? Of course free software is favoured as money is short as always.

Erich

Answer (score 1):

I think the Zimbra may be the solution for you. It has great group calendars very similar to MS Exchange.

http://www.zimbra.com/products/calendar-collaboration.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. Meanwhile our needs have changed. But I learned from it that I would have wanted a calendar server. I will come back to Zimbra, if need arises again.